# Power BI / DAX return values from table from rows filtered out by slicer

Tags: powerbi, dax

[image]I have a table visualisation that shows the populations of countries and a toggle switch that flips between 'sold' and 'unsold'. (This works with a measure that checks is a country is present in a sales table and assigns a 1 or 0 which is then used as a filter on the table visualisation).

Various slicers in the dashboard are used to filter the data model and retain the details of sales. When 'unsold' is selected therefore, the relevant countries are already filtered out of the countries data table and it is not possible to display them with their populations.

At the moment the workaround is to use a duplicate countries table that only has a one way filter, so that the rows remain regardless of filtering. This means that other slicers which interact with the rest of the data model don't filter the table visualisation as desired.

I am sure this must be possible using some combination of CALCULATE(), FILTER() and ALL() but I haven't managed to achieve this.

N.B. I can force the unsold countries to appear in a table visualisation using a constant measure (with formula: measure_name = 0) in a column .

Apologies if this is not very well explained, any help much appreciated.

Thanks for reading,
S

Image attached to (hopefully!) explain problem better.
Real scenario is more complicated hence not screenshotting from PBI.

Comment: I think you might need to provide an example and the expected outcome.

Comment: Hi Seymour - have inserted image with details. Thanks, S

Comment: The first step to solve the problem is to remove those bidirectional relationship. Can you do that?

Comment: that's the problem... we need those unfortunately. Various dashboards with synched slicers and filtering on other fields needs to filter out redundant territories from visuals and territory slicers :-/

Comment: are you completely aware of all the possible side-effects you encounter with that data model (i.e. bi-directional relationship on Fact and Dimensions)?

Comment: yes I think so!